# SVN Properties change on working copy checkout

Tags: svn, properties, svn-checkout

I have an odd one that I've not been able to sort out yet. When I checkout a branch from SVN, I'm regularly seeing multiple, unrelated files, with *SVN property changes*, either directly after checkout, or after I change one or two files.

During the course of work on the branch, I change a few files; those changes are shown in 'svn stat' as normal. However other files have properties changed - nothing more. Anyone seen this before? Anyone have ideas?

Matt

Comment: What sort of properties are changing?  Is it always the same one?

Answer (score 2):

Subversion will change the value of `svn:mergeinfo` even if the file being merged itself doesn't change or there appears to be no differences between the files. The `svn:mergeinfo` is used to track where merges were done, and not whether a merge resulted in a change. That way, Subversion can say *This revision on this branch were already merged, so they shouldn't be merged again*.

I'm not fond of merge tracking through this property. An `svn merge` can report hundreds of files being changed, but a closer examination shows only a few were changed. The rest merely had their `svn:mergeinfo` property changed.

Sometimes developers purposefully *revert* back files that only had their `svn:mergeinfo` property changed, and just checkin the files that actually had their content changed. This, of course, results in even more files needing *merging* the next time around. Sometimes developers will *clean up* `svn:mergeinfo`which really messes things up.

`svn:mergeinfo` really causes a lot of confusion. In fact, sometimes I wish there was a switch where we could turn off merge tracking. There are some sites that are more comfortable tracking their own merges.

However, this is what we have, so I'll live with it, and train developers on it.

Answer (score 1):

Someone might have merged from another branch to "your" branch. SVN tracks which revisions have been merged to a branch, and updates the svn:mergeinfo property accordingly

(AFAIK, this only applies to Subverson 1.5 or higher).

Comment: fair point, but the files are always empty. I would have thought that if there was a merge, there would be some content change.

Comment: It is 1.5+. Before that however, people often used a script (svnmerge), which essentially did the same thing, although for a different property name.  The property would also usually be on the folder (since that's the level you merge at), not a file.

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo might be useful

Comment: Frank, forsvarir, thanks for your input and assistance today. I've done a bit more reading which has helped fill in the blanks in my understanding. 

Many thanks.